# Handling lifetime in a Boost ASIO server

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm attempting to basically re-create the boost async daytime server example with beast websockets.

Inside of the `handle_accept` method of the `rubymud_server` class I call `new_connection->handshake()`.  As soon as the function body exits I believe my `new_connection` loses all its reference counts and dies.  If that's the case, is it only by luck that this thing is returning a response?  Is the `ws_.async_accept` and `ws_.async_write` on the `ws_` member of `ws_connection` finishing before the shared_ptr is destroyed?

```
class ws_connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ws_connection> {
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<ws_connection> pointer;

    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    {
        return pointer(new ws_connection(io_service));
    }

    void handshake()
    {
        ws_.async_accept(boost::bind(&ws_connection::handle_accept, shared_from_this()));
    }

    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return ws_.next_layer();
    }

private:
    ws_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : ws_(io_service)
    {
        response_ << "Hello from obsidian-server!";
    }

    void handle_accept() {
        ws_.async_write(response_.data(), boost::bind(&ws_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void handle_write() {
        std::cout << "handle_write" << std::endl;
    }

    beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ws_;
    beast::streambuf response_;
};

class rubymud_server {
public:
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

    rubymud_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 33435))
    {
        start_accept();
    }

private:
    void start_accept()
    {
        ws_connection::pointer new_connection = ws_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
                boost::bind(
                        &rubymud_server::handle_accept,
                        this,
                        new_connection,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error
                )
        );
    }

    void handle_accept(ws_connection::pointer new_connection, const error_code& error) {
        new_connection->handshake();
        start_accept();
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    rubymud_server server(io_service);
    io_service.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I'll see what I can do. I feel that you don't understand what `io_service` is, so I'm gonna say that: `io_service` is a queue of async functions. Every async call to happen, is inside `io_service`'s queue.

When you construct your class, `io_service` is passed to it. **Assuming `io_service` is not going to be destroyed before the class** (and this is important), your next requirement is that the class's object remain alive until `io_service` queue is empty. To ensure that, you post functions to `io_service` with pointers of `shared_from_this()`. Meaning, that as long as there is an instance of the `shared_ptr` alive inside `io_service`, your class will never be destroyed, because the `shared_ptr` counter is never zero.

Again: All this assumes that `io_service` will always be alive until the class's object is destroyed. Once the queue is empty, then automatically, there's no more shared pointers of `this`, and your `shared_ptr` can be safely destroyed.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yep.  Thanks.  I re-watched the asio cppcon video last night and they also confirmed this.  My confusion definitely was aroud how io_service worked.  The main thing was that I'm passing my `shared_from_this` ptrs into the `ws_` and `acceptor` async* methods for example - so I thought it was those objects who were managing the lifetime.  Turns out it's the underlying `io_service` as you mention

Comment: @SeanBollin Glad you got it. One note: Since we're talking about `shared_ptr`, always use `std::make_shared` or `boost::make_shared` instead of `new`. It's cleaner and a better style. Generally using the keyword `new` is bad-style unless you must.

Comment: although the original example I followed might be using `new` due to the constructor being private

Comment: If the constructor is private you can't even use new, because new calls the constructor. New is just the old way to do it. It's not a destruction recipe to use new in shared pointers, it's just bad-style. Btw, you must use new with unique pointers in C++11 because make_unique is C++14 (assuming you're not using boost). Using new is fading over time and being replaced with safer options.